# Hide Telerik tree view on Body Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using telerik tree view control

```
@(Html.Telerik().TreeView()

.Name("treeview")
)
```

and i am binding some tree nodes to this tree view. can u tell me how can i hide the tree view on body click.

Awaiting for your reply...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please let me know if you need anything from my side..thanks

Comment: Hide tree view on click of what exactly?  The page, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, something like this?

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    $("treeview").hide();
});
```